# How to load tier price table on category page

Tags: magento-1.7, category, tierprice

I want to display tier price table on my site's category page, but I have no idea regarding this at all. I have surf a lot but couldn't get any satisfactory solution. If any guy have an idea regarding this then please guide me. Your help would be appreciate a lot for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory this should work.

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

But it seams [there is an issue](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=8987) that wasn't fixed until now.
A possible workaround could be this:

```
<?php $this->setProduct(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($_product->getId()))?>
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
<?php $this->unsProduct($_product); // don't leave unnecessary data?>
```

Even if this works, I'm not sure it's a good idea to load the product in a loop (performance).
To overcome this, I think you can set the attribute `tier_price` to be `Used in Product Listing` and then you should be able to skip the `load` part and use only:

```
<?php $this->setProduct($_product)?>
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
<?php $this->unsProduct($_product); // don't leave unnecessary data?>
```

But I haven't tested it.

Comment: Sadly it hits in performance, 
Without this block my test site load the category view in 1.4s, after adding this line it incremented up to 2.7s. I'm trying to find another approach :)

Comment: Just to clarify. The last suggestion that @marius provide is faster :)